# Fatal error by starting django-celery with RabbitMQ [Unknown AMQP Method (10, 60)]

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to set up an instance of Django on a debian server with django-celery talking to RabbitMQ for distributed tasks.

I can get the RabbitMQ server set up and it'll respond with a good status, but as soon as celery makes contact with RabbitMQ, it throws an error and shuts down. Here's what it looks like when I try to start a dev instance of celery:

```
[2013-03-08 16:59:23,707: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@myserver ready.
[2013-03-08 16:59:23,725: INFO/MainProcess] consumer: Connected to amqp://celery_rabbit@127.0.0.1:5672//rabbit_vhost.
[2013-03-08 16:59:23,734: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: AMQPError('Unknown AMQP method (10, 60)', None, None, None, '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 351, in start
    component.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 392, in start
    self.reset_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 748, in reset_connection
    self.reset_pidbox_node()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 687, in reset_pidbox_node
    callback=self.on_control,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 71, in listen
    consumer.consume()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 401, in consume
    self._basic_consume(T, no_ack=no_ack, nowait=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 522, in _basic_consume
    no_ack=no_ack, nowait=nowait)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 571, in consume
    nowait=nowait)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1766, in basic_consume
    (60, 21),  # Channel.basic_consume_ok
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 69, in wait
    self.channel_id, allowed_methods)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 230, in _wait_method
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 71, in wait
    return self.dispatch_method(method_sig, args, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 85, in dispatch_method
    raise AMQPError('Unknown AMQP method %r' % (method_sig, ))
AMQPError: Unknown AMQP method (10, 60)
```

Just to confirm, I can check that RabbitMQ is still running afterwards:

```
# rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@myserver ...
[{running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","1.8.1"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.4.14"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.5"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.9.2"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.17"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.14"}]},
 {nodes,[{disc,[rabbit@myserver]}]},
 {running_nodes,[rabbit@myserver]}]
...done.
```

This is the last thing preventing me from launching my site and has me all frazzled, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downgrading kombu to 2.4.7 will fix it. The rabbitmq-server is not new enough to support AMQP 0-9-1.

Comment: You're right, thanks! Looks like these guys had the same problem: [github issue](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/217)

Answer (score 1):

I ran with the same problem in Ubuntu. 
It appears that (possibly depending on the Ubuntu version) the included RabbitMQ packages might be a outdated.
And the [RabbitMQ installation guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html) states that this is quite possible. Thus they recommend installing the .deb package from their web site.